# iOS how to catch event of switching standard keyboard type to number keypad?

Tags: ios, events, keypad

When switching to number keypad, I want to use my custom number keypad.
How to realize this function?
Apple don't give any APIs about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

there is a notification for change in UITextInputMode class

```
UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification
```

so add this notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardModeChange:) name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

i hope it should work for u. happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But your code can catch event of changing input type except switching to number keypad:( Do you see any other codes? Thank you.